# Prestashop 1.6 - Can't login into admin panel or add items to cart if I change php version

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, php-5.5

I have a Prestashop 1.6.1.14 (default theme) running on php 5.5.38 and I would like to update the php version... but when I set it to 5.6 (or higher ... up to 7.1) the site is visible (and no errors are displayed, not even in console) but it is not possible to add items to the cart nor  log into the administration panel. Not unless you change the PS_CIPHER_ALGORITHM value from 1 to 0 in the ps_configuration table. How much is it safe to change it? Does it weak the security on the site?

Any suggestion?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that sometimes, it's not easy to update to Prestahop 1.7 and so we get stick with the 1.6 version, so i suppose you can't update to 1.7.

In this case, can you try to update to the last version of 1.6 Prestashop (
[1.6.1.24](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6.1.24)  )

this version is compatible with php7 and run faster than php5

to update you can also use a [module autoupgrade](https://github.com/PrestaShop/autoupgrade/tree/4.14.1) from prestashop Team :

In the config of the module **AutoUpgrade** , choose "expert mode" and "minor version".

And don't forget to backup before changing the version.